# How can I get Items in nested folders in a SharePoint List?

Tags: list, powershell

I have a list with folders, multiple folders within each of the folders, and multiple items in each of the subfolders.

How do I iterate through the subfolders to get a similar output in PowerShell?

```
List
  Folder A
    Subfolder 1
      Item I
      Item II
      Item III
    Subfolder 2
      Item I
      Item II
      Item III
  Folder B
    Subfolder 1
      Item I
      Item II
      Item III
```

Comment: SharePoint Online or SharePoint server?

Comment: SharePoint server. 2013

Answer (score 1):

[through powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/65114/how-to-iterate-each-folders-in-each-of-the-sharepoint-websites-using-powershell) or

[c-sharp code](http://www.sharepointsecurity.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-development/iterating-recurring-through-nested-folders-in-c/)